# Calculating offsetWidth value is different in IE11 compared to Chrome

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is calculate the width of a dropdown element before it is shown and then add that width to the dropdown element.

In Chrome the Javascript works how it should and gives me a `width: 349px` which is correct, but in IE11 for some reason it calculates the width of that element to be `width: 89px` and I'm not entirely sure.

**Extra Info:**
The Navbar dropdowns are built like the one from [stripe.com](http://stripe.com) so they are hidden at first load although not hidden with `display: none` just hidden with `opacity: 0` so I don't think calculating the width should be a problem

The JS below is where the problem is but just in case you need the whole Javascript code for the dropdowns I have uploaded them to [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yct8hd2B)

**JS**

```
this.dropdownSections.forEach(function(section) {
  section.el.classList.remove("active");
  section.el.classList.remove("left");
  section.el.classList.remove("right");

  if (section.name == dropdownName) {
    section.el.classList.add("active");
    className = "right";

    // Width of the element is calculated here
    ddWidth = section.content.offsetWidth;
    ddHeight = section.content.offsetHeight;

    section.content.style.width = ddWidth + "px";
    section.content.style.height = ddHeight + "px";

    activeContent = section.content;

    if (options && options.keyboardNavigation) {
      self.registerArrowKeyNavigation(rootEl, section.el);
    }
  } else {
    section.el.classList.add(className);
  }
});
```

As you can see from the screenshot the results of Chrome vs IE11

[image: Dropdown Image 1]
[image: Dropdown Image 2]

Comment: Another reminder of why one should never, EVER trust Microsoft browsers to do ANYTHING right.

Comment: @Rob Yep, luckily it works on Edge but I really need to get it working on IE11